# Trying to overlay a Google Map with a CSS triangle arrow

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to place a CSS arrow over the top of a Google map. This is really a design feature, I have a horizontal stripe, half way along the stripe is a down arrow and I'd like the down arrow to overlay the Google map.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="blue-stripe text-center">
   <h1>how to find us</h1>
</div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="google-map">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2483.126971437045!2d-0.20244674881875546!3d51.51088651816963!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48760fe34117c0f5%3A0x5e396333c672dd3d!2s43+Ladbroke+Square%2C+London+W11!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1458754616197" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this, please note that I need to have my Google map behave responsively:

```
.blue-stripe {
    width: 100%;
    background: #223b74;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.blue-stripe h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #223b74;
    margin-left: 48%;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.google-map {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -10px;
    z-index: 0 !important;

}
.google-map iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    z-index: 0 !important;
    }
```

So I was hoping that z-index would sort this out.

Here is my example page: http://ladbroke.hardingweb.net/google-map.html. You should see that the google map overlays my arrow (I will push the Google map higher up for the production version).

I'd really appreciate any thoughts or insights

Many thanks
Nigel H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the property `position: relative` to your arrow. Solved the case in firefox and chrome for me.

Regards, hope it solves the issue.